# PHP Regular Expression Preg Replace to get Email

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have following syntax in my script to get email address from string. The email address contains - . 1234567890 _ characters. The email address is retrieved but not _ character before @ sign.

```
preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $value);
```

For example: The email address in string is ahmad_khalid@yahoo.com , with above syntax it returns khalid@yahoo.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to add in the _ character to your regex, so it would become

```
preg_replace("/<([a-z][_a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $value);
```

Alternately, you can do

```
preg_replace("/<([a-z][\w]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $value);
```

Using the "word character" \w as shorthand

Comment: bracket can be omitted around \w: preg_replace("/<([a-z]\w*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $value);